# First try at sorting an array

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray

I am trying to sort an array by the highest number that I assigned to each entry in the array.

However i don't think it's doing anything.
Any suggestions on where the error may be?

Thanks!

```
 - (NSArray*)sortByPercentage:(NSArray*)array {

    NSArray *inputArray = array;
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[ NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"percentMatched" ascending:YES];

    //nov 8
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *finalResult = [inputArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:finalResult];
}
```

Comment: what is "percentMatched"

Comment: it isnt...  it calculates a percentage and assigns it to the entry.  I am trying to filter from highest to lowest percentage.

Comment: also how would i only include entries that had a 20% or more?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this method, it's doing the job.Probably the mistake you do is at calling it, or the key is not valid.

Comment: for filtering you can use NSPredicateFilter.

Comment: What the data's model in your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm intrigued by why your sort doesn't work.  This does:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FooObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger value;
@property (readonly) NSInteger percentMatched;
@end

@implementation FooObject
@synthesize value;

//  compute percentMatched as an elementary function of value
- (NSInteger)percentMatched {
    return value * 2;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    FooObject *foo1 = [[FooObject alloc] init];
    foo1.value = 50;

    FooObject *foo2 = [[FooObject alloc] init];
    foo2.value = 5;

    FooObject *foo3 = [[FooObject alloc] init];
    foo3.value = 10;

    NSArray *myFoos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:foo1,foo2,foo3,nil];
    NSArray *sorters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"percentMatched" ascending:YES]];
    NSArray *mySortedFoos = [myFoos sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorters];
    for(FooObject *foo in mySortedFoos ) {
        printf("%ld ",foo.percentMatched);
    }
}
```

Prints `10 20 100` to the console as expected.

Comment: you were right... it works well, other methods were having the problem.  It was surprisingly fast!